# Finding the weak limit of a sequence of random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

> Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables having characteristic function $\chi(t)=e^{-|t|^{1.9}}$.Then what is the weak limit of $n^{-5/9}S_n$ as n gets large, where $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$?

I was trying to express the CDF of Sn in terms of the common CDF of Xi's and then use the relation between CDF and characteristic functions via the inversion formula.

And what  could possibly be said when  1.9 and 5/9 are replaced by any arbitrary exponent?

Can anyone help or suggest me anything?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given characteristic function of $X_i$, do you know there exists a formula, using independence, for the characteristic function of $S=\sum X_i$?

Comment: yes, i know,the characteristic function becomes the product of individuals.

Comment: You also have a result for $cX$

Comment: yes,then the characteristic function converges to 1 for every t,now i am thinking of what is the distribution whose characteristic function is a constant function?

Comment: I am guessing (from logic) that you get something degenerate, i.e., it converges to $0$.

Comment: yes,you are probably right,because if X is degenerate at a then characteristic function is exp(ita),now i am getting 1 for all t that means a has be to 0,and by uniqueness theorem for the characteristic function it has to be degenerate at 0.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let $\chi_n(t)$ denote the characteristic function of $S_n$, then
$$
\chi_n(t) = \chi(t)^n = \left(e^{-|t|^{1.9}}\right)^n = e^{-n|t|^{1.9}}.
$$

Can you simplify this based on $t$? e.g. if $|t|>1$ or if $|t|<1$ etc.?

Comment: but i have to deal with the factor n^(-5/9)

Comment: @SoumyadipSarkar **HINT** If $\phi(t)$ is the characteristic function for a random variable $X$, what is the characteristic function for $cX$ for some fixed $c \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes,then the characteristic function converges to 1 for every t,now i am thinking of what is the distribution whose characteristic function is a constant function?